# how to create flag for first working day of each month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I cannot find a solution for my current issue as I am quite new to Power BI and DAX. Thanks a lot for your help!!

I have a date table already. It contains the dates for several years and also a flag for the first working day per week (so weekends and holidays can be excluded). But I need a flag to mark the first workday of each month. I will later use that flag to some entries in another table specifically for the first workdays of all months contained in that fact table.

what I have:

| date | month | year | first_workday_per_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 |
| 02Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 |
| 03Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 |
| 04Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 1 |
| 05Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 |
| 06Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 11Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 1 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 01FEB2010 | 02 | 2010 | 1 |

I now have first workday per week, but need that for each month. Like...

| date | month | year | first_workday_per_week | first_workday_per_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 | 0 |
| 02Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 | 0 |
| 03Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 | 0 |
| 04Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 1 | 1 |
| 05Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 | 0 |
| 06Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 0 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 11Jan2010 | 01 | 2010 | 1 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 01FEB2010 | 02 | 2010 | 1 | 1 |

I tried to create a new column in my date table to see if I can find the correct date for the first workday of each month:

```
first_workday_per_month = CALCULATE(min(D_DATE[Date]), D_DATE[first_workday_per_week ]=1, month(D_DATE[Date]) = D_DATE[month])
```

However, that gives me only the first workday per year.
So I need some help finding the first workday per month and, if possible, the way to create the flag.

Creating the flag I'd do the following:

```
flag_workday_p_month = If(Calculate( First part of Question ) = DATE[date],1,0)
```

I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

KR,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the your date table with a `CALCULATE` if the year and month match the current row using `EARLIER`. Then filter if `first_workday_per_week = 1`. Take the `MIN` of those matching values to get the date, then compare it with an `IF` statement to the date in the current row.

```
first_workday_per_month = 
IF( CALCULATE( MIN ('D_DATE'[date]),
        FILTER ('D_DATE', 'D_DATE'[year] = EARLIER('D_DATE'[year]) ),
        FILTER ('D_DATE', 'D_DATE'[month] = EARLIER('D_DATE'[month]) ),
        'D_DATE'[first_workday_per_week] = 1 ) = 'D_DATE'[date],
    1, 0)
```